# How to create a constructor that returns a value without accessing a property

Tags: javascript, class

Suppose I have this class that makes a grid:

```
class Grid {
  constructor(w, h, fill) {
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.fill = fill;
    this.value = new Array(w).fill(null).map(() => new Array(h).fill(fill));
  }

  addAll() {
    let sum = 0;
    this.value.forEach(row => row.forEach(n => sum += n));
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Here's an example of it in use:

```
const myGrid = new Grid(2, 3, 1); // Creates a 2x3 grid made out of 1s
myGrid.addAll(); // 6
myGrid.value; // [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I want to know if there's a way to completely skip `myGrid.value` and instead use `myGrid` where it still returns the same thing.

You can see this in the array constructor:

```
const myArray = new Array(3).fill(1);
myArray; // [1, 1, 1] (Notice it's not myArray.value)
```

Comment: If myGrid is your value then what happens to w, h, and fill? You are creating an object with multiple fields. value is a field like others. If you want a single field object, then use Array.

Comment: you can't do that in javascript. you could override `valueOf` but that won't solve all issues.

Comment: `Array` is special.

Comment: If I am right, Array isn't that special, and you could just write something like this[0]=5. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the case that you want to return an Array, it's probably better to write `grid` as a normal function instead of a class

```js
const grid = (rows, cols, value) =>
  rows === 0
    ? []
    : [ Array(cols).fill(value) ] .concat (grid (rows - 1, cols, value))
    
console.log (grid (2, 3, 1))
// [ [ 1, 1, 1 ]
// , [ 1, 1, 1 ]
// ]

console.log (grid (4, 4, 'x'))
// [ [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]
// , [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]
// , [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]
// , [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with plain arrays and a factory approach instead:

```js
class Grid {
  static of (w, h, fill) {
    return new Array(w).fill(null).map(() => new Array(h).fill(fill));
  }

  static addAll(grid) {
    let sum = 0;
    grid.forEach(row => row.forEach(n => sum += n));
    return sum;
  }
}

const grid = Grid.of(3, 2, 1);
const sum = Grid.addAll(grid);

console.log(grid); // [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
console.log(sum);  // 6
```